# Modern explanation of the Burkitt's lymphoma geography

Tags: cancer, herpes, lymph-nodes, endemic

In Dr. Arnold Levine "Viruses", a book published in 1991, it's noted that while association between Burkitt's lymphoma and the Epstein-Barr virus is established, the correlation between the geography of the lymphoma cases and the African malaria belt is yet to be explained.

After 30 years of research, do we have a better understanding what environmental factors provoke the cancer?

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Comment: My layman understanding after reading the NIH paper published in 2008 is that we have better geographic boundaries, but not factors.

Comment: What NIH paper published in 2008? That's what I'm asking, and I'm asking you to add it to the question, not just reply to me in comments. Your question lacks prior research. Adding a link to that paper and a quote from it highlighting the part you think is relevant would fix that problem.